# Empty string Sql Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to update these empty space records to empty strings but even if say it updated doesn't update. I run command over and over again it still says X rows affected. data type var char(2) I converto to nvarchar(2) still same

```
UPDATE Foo SET Boo = '' where Boo = ' '
```

> (21297 row(s) affected)

MS Sql 2012

Comment: And what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: This seems very much straight foreword Update command  but wonder why not work for you, Have you tried `SET Boo = N''` , just asking nt solution

Comment: just tried, result same It keeps updating.

Comment: as I understand '' and ' ' are equal in mssql? when I changed to nvarchar fields has '' now but still answering to where Boo = ' '

Comment: No - space and empty string are not the same thing

Comment: This will help you: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/behavior-of-varchar-with-spaces-at-the-end, use `LIKE` to compare

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below query.

```
  UPDATE Foo 
   SET Boo = '' 
  WHERE replace(Boo,' ','')= ''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update all your empty spaces to empty string use this query.

```
UPDATE Foo
SET Boo = ''
WHERE len(ltrim(rtrim(Boo))) = 0
and Boo is not null
```